# How to make ellipsis media heading in second line using Bootstrap Media object

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How to make ellipsis media heading in the second line using Bootstrap Media object?

The image below shows 3 lines, how can I limit it only 2 lines then ellipsis

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this using css

```css
.media-body h5 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

img {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="media">
  <img class="mr-3" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Blue_copyright.svg/250px-Blue_copyright.svg.png" alt="image">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</h5>
    Description does here
  </div>
</div>
```